# Extract the number from the Title column in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

Please help the query extract the number after "_tid-" from the Title column.

[image]

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe via text. Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Vertica Regular Expression function collection. Regular expressions in Vertica correspond to the perl regex functionality in their behaviour.

So, with your input, search for the first group that follows `_tid-` and consists of consecutive digits (`\d`)...

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in final query ...
indata(Title,Extract_ID) AS (
          SELECT 'sdffsdvprocessortype%3Alnjklel&text=&textSearch=&pageSize=10&SSid=psj6tcd5b1g7_tid-87945','87945'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/hk/en/age.html?SSid=ps_c8x4v1r2a3_tid-8952777456','8952777456'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/hk/en/ge/dhci.html?SSid=ps_7228fk5sbh_tid-5879','5879'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/fr/fr/c/3328412?q=%3%3AtSearch=&pageSize=10&SSid=pseydgg8h2_tid-9858867','9858867'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/fr/fr/seas/1011028701?SSid=ps_yne5j6fmqv_tid-6879582','6879582'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/il/en/sera/p/1010192786?SSid=ps_gydi5nk673_tid-5577484126','5577484126'
UNION ALL SELECT 'pid=ps_98qcokfh3_tid-548965&q=%3Arelevance%3Afacet_Processorstype','548965'
UNION ALL SELECT 'pid=ps_345ey5na9_tid-95861469rq=%3relevance%3Afacet_Processo','95861469'
UNION ALL SELECT 'npyamjhsgx_tid-002154785%20/p/1010192775?SSid=ps_npyamjhsgx_tid-002154785','002154785'
UNION ALL SELECT 'https://www.google.com/us/en/ke.html?ssid=ps_wc998kn__tid-0012889','0012889'
)
-- end of your input, real query starts here ...
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    title          -- input string
  , '_tid-(\d+)'    -- regular experssion (note the bit in parentheses, that's the first group)
  , 1              -- starting point
  , 1              -- occurrence ordinal number
  , ''             -- modifier (case insensitive, etc. check perl docu)
  , 1              -- parentheses base grouping expression's ordinal number
  ) AS calc_extract
, *
FROM indata;
-- out  calc_extract |                                             Title                                              | Extract_ID 
-- out --------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------
-- out  87945        | sdffsdvprocessortype%3Alnjklel&text=&textSearch=&pageSize=10&SSid=psj6tcd5b1g7_tid-87945       | 87945
-- out  8952777456   | https://www.google.com/hk/en/age.html?SSid=ps_c8x4v1r2a3_tid-8952777456                        | 8952777456
-- out  5879         | https://www.google.com/hk/en/ge/dhci.html?SSid=ps_7228fk5sbh_tid-5879                          | 5879
-- out  9858867      | https://www.google.com/fr/fr/c/3328412?q=%3%3AtSearch=&pageSize=10&SSid=pseydgg8h2_tid-9858867 | 9858867
-- out  6879582      | https://www.google.com/fr/fr/seas/1011028701?SSid=ps_yne5j6fmqv_tid-6879582                    | 6879582
-- out  5577484126   | https://www.google.com/il/en/sera/p/1010192786?SSid=ps_gydi5nk673_tid-5577484126               | 5577484126
-- out  548965       | pid=ps_98qcokfh3_tid-548965&q=%3Arelevance%3Afacet_Processorstype                              | 548965
-- out  95861469     | pid=ps_345ey5na9_tid-95861469rq=%3relevance%3Afacet_Processo                                   | 95861469
-- out  002154785    | npyamjhsgx_tid-002154785%20/p/1010192775?SSid=ps_npyamjhsgx_tid-002154785                      | 002154785
-- out  0012889      | https://www.google.com/us/en/ke.html?ssid=ps_wc998kn__tid-0012889                              | 0012889
```